# mysqli->real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I got a problem with real_escape_string

code:

```
function mysql_escape($str){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(self::$link);
    echo '</pre>';

    return self::$link->real_escape_string($str);
}
```

output:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (17) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  NULL
  ["client_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50051)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  NULL
  ["error"]=>
  NULL
  ["field_count"]=>
  NULL
  ["host_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["server_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["server_version"]=>
  NULL
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  NULL
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  NULL
  ["thread_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["warning_count"]=>
  NULL
}



Warning:  mysqli::real_escape_string() [mysqli.real-escape-string]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /usr/www/users/.../class/class.Data.php on line 188
```

Comment: Couldn't fetch mysqli in ...   in **what**?

Comment: is the connection opened correctly? I assume you've got something like `self::$link = new mysqli(...);`. If it can't connect, it doesn't return false, but an object, so in any case, `if (self::$link)` would always evaluate to true. Try `mysqli_connect_error()` or `self::$link->connect_error()` (depending on your php version) as stated in [mysli::__construct](http://php.net/mysqli.connect)

Comment: @carlos that should probably be an answer :)

Comment: check my question again.. update

Comment: do `var_dump(self::$link->connect_error);`.

Comment: Hm... so it seems it's not a connection error. Maybe the connection has been closed? Do you see something in `var_dump(self::link)`?

Comment: object(mysqli)#1 (17) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(7) "5.0.51a"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50051)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(31) "sql89.your-server.de via TCP/IP"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(8) "5.1.30-2"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50130)
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(5723651)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: mysqli\_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973330/warning-mysqli-query-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the connection opened correctly? I assume you've got something like

```
self::$link = new mysqli(...);
```

If it can't connect, it doesn't return `false`, but an object, so in any case, your conditional always evaluates to `true`:

```
if (self::$link)
{
     echo "I'm always here!"
}
```

Try `mysqli_connect_error()` or `self::$link->connect_error()` (depending on your php version) as stated in [mysqli::__construct](http://php.net/mysqli.connect)