# Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem where I can not retrieve the result from my MySQL database (via PHP). I use the same function in other places and it works flawlessly. However at this point i keep getting the "Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli" error. Details of the problem are explained below.
I use a quite similar function elsewhere (getAllCountries as seen below) in my PHP which does work perfectly:

```
function getAllCountries()
{
    $result = db_query("SELECT countryid, name FROM country ORDER BY name ASC");

    echo "<select class=addresscountry name=country>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<option value="' . $row['countryid'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";

    mysqli_close(db_connect());
}
```

So the problem is the following:

I have a php file containing the following code:

```
<?php
require 'includes/functions.php';

function getUserPicPath()
{
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

    $result = db_query("SELECT picture FROM user WHERE userid='$userid'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $picturepath = $row['picture'];
    }

    echo $picturepath;

    mysqli_close(db_connect());
}
```

my functions.php file has the following line (together with other non-relevant functions):

```
require 'dbfunctions.php';
```

and my dbfunctions.php looks like this:

```
<?php
function db_connect()
{
    require ".db_password.php";

    static $connection;

    if(!isset($connection)) {
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,$dbname);
    }

    if($connection === false) {
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }

    return $connection;
}

function db_query($query) 
{
    $connection = db_connect();

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    return $result;
}
```

In my PHP document I call the following function :

```
if ($userid == -1)
    {
        showNotAuthorizedPage();
    } else {
        myAccountPage();
    }
```

and the myAccountPage() function is declared in the same file as the getUserPicPath() function, this getUserPicPath() function is called as follows:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p><?php getUserPicPath(); ?></p>
  </div>
```

I use the tabs (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) on my webpage and that is where i want to call it in.
The myAccountPage() function which gives the following error :

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\Dennis\Documents\My Dropbox\xxx\zzz\www\Project Files\includes\dbfunctions.php on line 29
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  256880  {main}( )   ..\myaccount.php:0
2   0.0010  283328  myAccountPage( )    ..\myaccount.php:181
3   0.0070  285368  getUserPicPath( )   ..\myaccount.php:121
4   0.0070  285528  db_query( ) ..\myaccount.php:11
5   0.0070  285624  mysqli_query ( )    ..\dbfunctions.php:29

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\Users\Dennis\Documents\My Dropbox\me&roxy\WE\final project\Project Files\myaccount.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  256880  {main}( )   ..\myaccount.php:0
2   0.0010  283328  myAccountPage( )    ..\myaccount.php:181
3   0.0070  285368  getUserPicPath( )   ..\myaccount.php:121
4   0.0080  285768  mysqli_fetch_array ( )  ..\myaccount.php:13

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: picturepath in C:\Users\Dennis\Documents\My Dropbox\me&roxy\WE\final project\Project Files\myaccount.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  256880  {main}( )   ..\myaccount.php:0
2   0.0010  283328  myAccountPage( )    ..\myaccount.php:181
3   0.0070  285368  getUserPicPath( )   ..\myaccount.php:121

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\Dennis\Documents\My Dropbox\me&roxy\WE\final project\Project Files\myaccount.php on line 19
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  256880  {main}( )   ..\myaccount.php:0
2   0.0010  283328  myAccountPage( )    ..\myaccount.php:181
3   0.0070  285368  getUserPicPath( )   ..\myaccount.php:121
4   0.0100  285864  mysqli_close ( )    ..\myaccount.php:19
```

Comment: That's not the complete information available. Just like you check for connection errors, you should check for query errors as well. I'm not familiar with mysqli but if you open the manual you'll find stuff with `error` on its name.

Comment: Why are you running your query in `getUserPicPath()` twice? What does the `echo` after the first call give you?

Comment: I'd also recommend checking to see what's in `mysqli_error()`, so you can see what error the database is passing back

Comment: I can not seem to get any errors, everything is just null and nothing else except the "Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli" is displayed. However I did notice that when in the myaccount.php I call the function directly it is working as intended, so using <?php getUserPicPath(); ?> instead of using <?php myAccountPage(); ?> seems to work (this is not what I want though...). I have edited my question and added more details in the php/mysqli returned error

Comment: why you have written require ".db_password.php"; inside db_connect() function ? there is "." before db_

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong with your database connection workflow. Anyway why don't you remove the mysqli_close(db_connect()) statement and try to run the script without it. Either way when the script ends the mysql connection is usually closed automatically

Answer (score 13):

I think it is because when you close the database connection the first time, you forget to do:

```
unset($connection);
```

And then when you try connecting to the database again, it craps out because it is still set to the closed connection.

Answer (score -3):

You forgot the include your database connection. Just add the `$connection` to your sql query:

```
function getAllCountries()
{
    $result = db_query($connection,"SELECT countryid, name FROM country ORDER BY name ASC");

    // enter code here
}
```