# PHP mysql error, unable to INSERT to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have these lines of PHP code:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO TableName ... " //an example, line is very long
error_log($sql2);
$result2 = $this->conn->query($sql2); //line 81
```

I get this error in PHP error log:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /volume1/web/DB_Functions.php on line 81
```

My first idea was that my **$sql2** string is not valid, but when I copied it from PHP error log and pasted it to **PhpMyAdmin** as SQL it works pretty well, what could be wrong?

Comment: How are you initializing your mysql connection ? maybe you didn't set it up correctly

Comment: Paste your full code!!

Comment: Show use the code of $this->conn->query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because when you close the database connection the first time, you forget to do:

```
unset($this->conn);
```

And then when you try connecting to the database again, it craps out because it is still set to the closed connection.
Originally referenced from: [Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973330/warning-mysqli-query-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Hope it solve your problem!